# How to accept enter as valid input to Scanner.nextLine()?

Tags: java

I just want the scanner to read new line as empty string then continue to next process if the user press enter. So valid input must be y,n,enter. Any idea how to do this?

This is my code:

```
String gender = "", employed = "";
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Gender M/F, press enter to skip... ");
while(!in.hasNext("[mfMF]$")){
    System.out.print("Invalid, please choose m/f only... ");
    in.nextLine();
}
if(in.hasNextLine()){
    gender = in.nextLine();
}
System.out.print("Employed? y/n, press enter to skip... ");
    while(!in.hasNext("[ynYN]$|")){
        System.out.print("Invalid, please choose y/n only... ");
        in.nextLine();
    }
if(in.hasNextLine()){
    employed = in.nextLine();
}
System.out.println(gender + " : " + employed);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This :

```
import java.util.*;

class Scanner1
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
     Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
     String s;
     do
     {
        s=sc.nextLine();
           if(!(s.equalsIgnoreCase("y")||s.equalsIgnoreCase("n")||s.equalsIgnoreCase("")))
        {
            System.out.println("Please Enter valid input");
        }

    }while(!(s.equalsIgnoreCase("y")||s.equalsIgnoreCase("n")||s.equalsIgnoreCase("")));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, to check if the user has pressed enter, you would have to make use of the *isEmpty()* method. The way to do that is shown below:

```
String enter = in.nextLine();
if (enter.isEmpty()) {
   // do what is needed
}
```